# Golang swaggo nullable

Tags: go, swagger, swagger-2.0

I use swaggo/swag v1.8.6

how can I set notice that field is nullable?

I tried to write  extensions:"x-nullable", but it has no effect

```
type MyStruct struct {
 Field1 string `json:"field_id,omitempty"  extensions:"x-nullable"`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have made a workaround

by creating fix.sh at <project_dir>/docs

```
#!/bin/sh

sed -i "s/x-nullable/nullable/g" ./docs/docs.go
sed -i "s/x-omitempty/omitempty/g" ./docs/docs.go
sed -i "s/x-nullable/nullable/g" ./docs/swagger.json
sed -i "s/x-omitempty/omitempty/g" ./docs/swagger.json
sed -i "s/x-nullable/nullable/g" ./docs/swagger.yaml
sed -i "s/x-omitempty/omitempty/g" ./docs/swagger.yaml
```

and running swaggo by

```
swag init -g cmd/app/main.go && ./docs/fix.sh
```